# Abort BGSAVE Already in process

Tags: database, redis

I started saving `redis-db` snapshot by calling `BGSAVE` command in `redis-cli`.

It has started running but I keep getting these errors in the logs

```
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:41.129 # Background saving error
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:47.043 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:47.058 * Background saving started by pid 13204
[13204] 27 Jan 07:18:47.058 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:47.158 # Background saving error
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:53.070 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:53.085 * Background saving started by pid 13207
[13207] 27 Jan 07:18:53.085 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:53.186 # Background saving error
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:59.098 * 1 changes in 900 seconds. Saving...
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:59.113 * Background saving started by pid 13210
[13210] 27 Jan 07:18:59.114 # Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied
[30853] 27 Jan 07:18:59.213 # Background saving error
```

looks like the `redis BGSAVE` command is running indefinitely. How to stop this.

Also I tried checking for process pid by `ps -aux| grep redis` command.

```
13196 pts/11   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto redis
30853 ?        Ssl  1292:57 /usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

There is no process to kill.

EDIT: These are the permissions to redis folder and dump.rdb file

```
f: /var/lib/redis
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  var
drwxr-xr-x root  root  lib
drwxr-xr-x redis redis redis

f: /var/lib/redis/dump.rdb
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  var
drwxr-xr-x root  root  lib
drwxr-xr-x redis redis redis
-rw-rw-rw- redis redis dump.rdb
```

EDIT2: Got the answer. The problem was somehow the config parameters are changed. The `dbfilename` and `dir` values are changed.

Set these values to original through `CONFIG SET` command and now its working fine. Adding in-case somebody has same problem.

But the question is how did they change. Did this happen to anybody else?

Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try and fix the file permissions error (does the default save location exist and does redis have permission to write to it?) or you can disable saving with:

```
config set save ""
```

Comment: I have modified permissions as well, it is still not working. I have updated the permissions in EDIT.

Comment: If CONFIG REWRITE fails, check that for redis.conf setype is redis_var_lib_t .